# Who is responsible for checking state?

Tags: go, logic, repository, single-responsibility-principle, chain-of-responsibility

I'm currently building a consent management system consisting of 3 layers:

- Handlers/Controllers (Rest)
- Services (Logic)
- Repositories (Microsoft SQL)

**This is the scenario:**

I'm fetching the identifier (Id) from a model inside of the database. But before that, I have to check if a boolean of another model is set to true or false. I had a discussion with one of our engineers on how to implement his, and furthermore who is responsible for the checking: Business logic or repository layer by SQL queries.

**Solution 1:**
Fetch the whole model/instance from the repository layer by two parameters and then explicitly check the state of the boolean. (true/false) Using the following query:

`SELECT * FROM [ApplicationUserMapping] WHERE Uuid = @Uuid AND ApplicationUuid=@ApplicationUuid;`

Code inside the business logic:

```
if !applicationUserMapping.HasConsent {
    // User is NOT allowed to proceed -> Error messaging -> Logging -> etc.
}

// User is allowed to proceed -> Continue code block
```

**Solution 2:**
Or write and execute a query that checks if the state of the boolean. (true/false) The repository is now responsible for checking the state. And return the values depending on the outcome of the query.

`SELECT * FROM [ApplicationUserMapping] WHERE Uuid = @Uuid AND ApplicationUuid=@ApplicationUuid AND HasConsent = 1;`

**Solution 3:**
If you understand my scenario and have a better solution please provide it.

Comment: Do you have data for `applicationUserMapping.HasConsent` before reading from database?

Comment: 99.9% of the time an "SQL-only" approach will save query round trips between app and database and thus be far more performant, with less latency and lower resource usage on app and DB.  Many dev teams prefer to do database schema design "through" their ORM or models, in which case the performance benefit of raw SQL *may* be outweighed by the difficulty of aligning ad hoc queries with "model managed" database schemas.    Most ORMs also support adding conditions to queries without having to do comparison logic "outside" the query.

Comment: You need to make a query anyway. Might as well have the DB filter it for you. There are situations where solution #1 is acceptable, such as when the creation of temporary tables would be required (debug difficulty +1) to even make the logic happen on the DB. I do however find that plain old SQL-statements get hit with the ORM-club-of-death more often than really is beneficial to the project and those working on it.

Comment: @advayrajhansa No you only have the two parameters (@Uuid and @ApplicationUuid) available. You need these parameters to fetch the instance from the database. Then you can either check the instance on HasConsent. Or instantly fetch the database using the HasConsent = true in the SQL query.

Comment: @DanielFarrell But what if the query doesn't return any resuls SqlNoRows. How do I check if the query failed on one of the two Uuids (parameters) or because the consent is false. Especially the last scenario is important for me. So I can explicitly do some error messsaging for the consent status.